# Drag objects from JList, with ghost image effect

Tags: java, swing, jlist, drag-and-drop

I have added to one of the JLists in my java program a Drag and Drop transfer handler.
I added a method to this JList so as to have a nice ghost image effect of the selected values I am dragging. This effect works just fine until I add the transfer handler :

In that case, this method :

```
myList.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("Dragging");            
    }
});
```

from :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.swing.*;

class ListExample extends   JFrame
{

private JPanel      topPanel;
private JList       myList;

public ListExample()
{

    setSize(300, 100 );
    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    getContentPane().add( topPanel );

    String  listData[] =
        {
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
            "Item 4"
        };


    myList = new JList(listData);
    myList.setDragEnabled(true);
    ListItemTransferHandler handler = new ListItemTransferHandler();
    myList.setTransferHandler(handler);
    topPanel.add( myList, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    myList.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("Dragging");            
        }
    });
}

public static void main( String args[] )
{

    ListExample mainFrame = new ListExample();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true );
}
class ListItemTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
    private final DataFlavor localObjectFlavor;
    private Object[] transferedObjects = null;
    public ListItemTransferHandler() {
        localObjectFlavor = new ActivationDataFlavor(Object[].class, DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType, "Array of items");
    }
    private JList source = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
        source = (JList) c;
        transferedObjects = source.getSelectedValues();
        return new DataHandler(transferedObjects, localObjectFlavor.getMimeType());
    }
    @Override public boolean canImport(TransferSupport info) {

        return true;

    }
    @Override public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return MOVE; //TransferHandler.COPY_OR_MOVE;
    }



}
}
```

gets called once or twice as I begin to drag, but as soon as I get a few pixels away, the source selection changes colour and my dragmouse listener is no longer called, and the ghost image stays nearby the source of the dragged object.
However, I can still drag my selected cells and drop them where I want. It's just that the ghost image doesn't follow all the way.
I am obviously missing something important here but since it is a rather specific problem I couldn't find help anywhere, so suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This could be a specific behavior (ghost image) for your OS, but not standard Java feature. Usually to create such effect you will have to do a lot of additional coding and put some effort into it...

Comment: As it happens this feature is not supported in Windows, and that is why I would like to make a custom one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DragGestureListener taks precedence on MouseMotionListener when a Drag-n-Drop process is started. This you've got to implement such a DragGestureListener.
See here for a good working example.
[Java drag and drop custom cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729078/java-drag-and-drop-custom-cursor)